# Create a map of a game's portals

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Given a set of rooms, each with a N, a S, an E, and a W exit/entrance to another of the rooms, create as simple a map as possible that graphically represents their connections.

The rooms in question are the level 3 rooms of the Watcher's Keep from the Baldur's Gate 2 Throne of Bhaal game. There is no need to play or search much; the rooms and their connections are neatly described [here](http://mikesrpgcenter.com/bgate2/maps/ar3003.html), where each room is represented by its ingame code = AR<4-digits unique room identifier>.

Further notes:

1. The north is the top left corner. Alternatively, you may use
   SW/SE/NW/NE
2. A few rooms only have N/S entrance/exit points
3. An exit is not only associated with a room, but with an entrance to this room. (In the game, when going to an exit, you appear at a
   specific entrance to the next room, not in an arbitrary point in
   it).
4. Two entrance/exits are not necessarily "mutual". If I go though an exit to a new room, and then step into the exit of where I spawned,
   it might not return me to the same place.
5. There should be no "teleportation portals" in the result.

My intuition tels me this is not a plane graph, thus multiple levels should be used. I have constructed a solution atm which has all but one room located in the "0 level" in multiple rotations, and one room in the second level upside-down (antigravity?). The simpler the final design the better.

Please tell me if this needs any modification!

Comment: At first I was thinking this wasn't really a puzzle, but upon closer inspection it seems very Jigsaw puzzle like :)

Comment: :) fact is, I've been trying to make a map just so...that I can have a map. Seeing numbers everywhere just gives a headache....or an interesting puzzle.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. Although I see 9 connects to 5, but 5 doesn't connect to 9. That complicates things a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That took a little bit to build. Unless otherwise noted all paths are bidirectional. The indicate the rotation needed to get back to the original orientation. Positive being clockwise, negative being counter-clockwise.

For example, AR3009 needs to be rotated clockwise 90 degrees to get back to the image in the OP's link.

> [image: Baldur's gate map]

Comment: Nice one. Are there rotations that you haven't mentioned? For example, if somebody is in (the all-too-complicated) 9, they would have to rotate your drawing 90 degrees counterclockwise to correctly choose their route to another room.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that. Yes I made some rotations, I'll edit my picture accordingly.